# return the sum of the max sublist

Tags: list, python-3.x, sum, max, minimum

I have to write a function that takes a list of integers and returns the maximum sum sublist of the list. An example would be:

```
l = [4,-2,-8,5,-2,7,7,2,-6,5]
```

returns `19`

so far my code is:

```
count = 0
for i in range(0,len(l)-1):
    for j in range(i,len(l)-1):
        if l[i] >= l[j]:

            count += l[i:j]

return count
```

I am kind of stuck and confused, can anyone help?
Thank You!

Comment: The naive approach would be to check every possible sublist of all lengths 1..`len(l)`. That is, you would check every sublist length 1, then every sublist length 2, then every sublist length 3, and output the maximum found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum sum sublist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062844/maximum-sum-sublist)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a homework, so I won't try to google algorithms here and/or post too much code.

Some ideas (just from the top of my head, 'cause I like these kind of tasks :-))

As user lc already pointed out the naive, and also exhaustive way is to test every single sublist. I believe your (user2101463) code goes in that direction. Just use `sum()` to build up the sums and compare against a known best. To prime the best known sum with a reasonable starting value, just use the first value of the list.

```
the_list = [4,-2,-8,5,-2,7,7,2,-6,5]

best_value = the_list[0]
best_idx = (0,0)
for start_element in range(0, len(the_list)+1):
    for stop_element in range(start_element+1, len(the_list)+1):
        sum_sublist = sum(the_list[start_element:stop_element])
        if sum_sublist > best_value:
            best_value = sum_sublist
            best_idx = (start_element, stop_element)

print("sum(list([{}:{}])) yields the biggest sum of {}".format(best_idx[0], best_idx[1], best_value))
```

This of course has quadratic runtime O(N^2). That means: If the problem size, as defined by the number of elements of the input list, grows with N, the runtime grows with N*N, with some arbitrary coefficients.

Some heuristics for improvement:

- Obviously negative numbers are not good because they decrease the achievable sum
- If you encounter a sequence of negative numbers, restart your best sublist after that sequence, if the sum of the best list so far plus the negative numbers is < 0. In your example list the first three numbers cannot be part of a best list because the positive effect of the `4` is always negated by the `-2, -8`.
- Possibly this even leads to an `O(N)` implementation which just iterates from start to end, memorizing the best known start index while calculating running sums of a full total from that start index as well as positive and negative subtotals of the last continues sequence of positive and negative numbers, respectively.
- Once such a best list is found, possibly this requires a final cleanup to remove a trailing negative sublist such as the `-6, 5` at the end of your example.

Hope this leads in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the 'maximum subarray problem' and can be done in linear time. The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) has your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most optimal solution is which takes linear runtime that is O(n).But this problem has "n*lgn" runtime solution(based on divide and conquer algorithm) and  "n^2" runtime solution.If you are interested in those algorithms here is the link [introduction to algorithms](https://www.amazon.in/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen-ebook/dp/B007CNRCAO?ie=UTF8&keywords=introduction%20to%20algorithms&qid=1467634087&ref_=sr_1_1&s=books&sr=1-1) which is highly recommended and here I write a code in **java** which has linear runtime.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int []A=new int[n];
    int highestsum=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int sumvariable=0;
    int x=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        A[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sumvariable+=A[i];
        if(sumvariable<0)
        {
            if(sumvariable>=highestsum)
            {
                highestsum=A[i];
                sumvariable=A[i];
            }
            else
            {
                sumvariable=0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(sumvariable>highestsum)
            {
                highestsum=sumvariable;
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println(highestsum);
}
```