# Generative recursion to find the sublist with the maximum sum

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, sublist

I am trying to solve a generative recursion problem in Python. The question is:

- In a list that consists of integers, find the adjoining sublist which has 
  the largest sum and return that sum.
- For example, if the given list is  [−2, 1, −3, 4, −1, 2, 1, −5, 4], the adjoining sublist which has the largest sum is [4, −1, 2, 1], which has a sum 6

I have to follow the given algorithm to solve find_max:

1. Split given list (at the midpoint) into two: L_left and L_right.
2. Return the maximum value of following 3:

   - The maximum sum of any sublist resides entirely in L_left (using a recursive call to find_max).
   - The maximum sum of any sublist resides entirely in L_right (using a recursive call to find_max).
   - The maximum sublist that overlaps L_left and L_right; i.e.,

     - First: Find max sum of any sublist starting from the midpoint (towards the left) and      ending at some point 
       on the left of the midpoint
     - Second: Find the max sum of any sublist starting from the midpoint (towards the 
       right) and ending at some point on the right of the midpoint
     - Finally: Add the two max sums.

I have tried the following:

```
def find_max(L):
    length = len(L)
    mid_index = length/2
    if length == 1:
        return L[0]
    else:
        left = find_max(L[0:(length/2)])
        right = find_max(L[(length/2):length])
        max_subset = max(left,right,left+right)
        return max_subset
```

This is able to solve for lists with length 2. How do I extend this to work for a list with more elements?

Comment: Can you define "adjoining sublist", becuase I don't understand how `[1, 2, -1, 4]` and an adjoining sublist of `[−5, 1, 4, −2, 2, −1, 2, −3, 1, −3, 4]`. As I understanding the adjoining sublist with the maximum value would be `[1, 4, -2, 2, -1, 2]` with a sum of 6.

Comment: `[1, 2, -1, 4]` is not a sublist of `[−5, 1, 4, −2, 2, −1, 2, −3, 1, −3, 4]`. Is there a typo?

Comment: One hint when using recursion: the @memoize decorator helps wonders to make a recursion go faster since recursion is in general a bad idea, due to time consumption - if you are interested in it: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize   i know thats not really an answer to your question, though it is an important remark to make

Comment: @memoize doesn't change the algorithm.

Comment: If you can afford to _not_ use a divide and conquer solution, I'd honestly suggest this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062844/maximum-sum-sublist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't consider following:

- another base case: L is []
- left half and right half should be consecutive.

  - According to your code, if `L` is `[2, -5, 3]`, in the first recursion, `left + right` will yield 5.

---

```
def find_max(L):
    length = len(L)
    mid_index = length/2
    if length == 0:
        return 0
    elif length == 1:
        return max(L[0], 0)

    left = find_max(L[:mid_index])
    right = find_max(L[mid_index:])

    left_half = right_half = 0
    # to the left
    accum = 0
    for x in L[mid_index-1::-1]:
        accum += x
        left_half = max(left_half, accum)

    # to the right
    accum = 0
    for x in L[mid_index:]:
        accum += x
        right_half = max(right_half, accum)

    return max(left, right, left_half + right_half)


assert find_max([]) == 0
assert find_max([-1]) == 0
assert find_max([1, 2, 3]) == 6
assert find_max([2, -5, 3]) == 3
assert find_max([-5, 1, 4, -2, 2, -1, 2, -3, 1, -3, 4]) == 6
```

---

Without for loop:

```
def sum_max(L, accum=0, max_value=0):
    if not L:
        return max_value
    accum += L[0]
    return sum_max(L[1:], accum, max(max_value, accum))

def find_max(L):
    ...
    left_half = sum_max(L[mid_index-1::-1])
    right_half = sum_max(L[mid_index:])
    ...
```