# finding contiguous Subset with Largest Sum

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

```
def max_sublist(x):
 max1 = 0
 max2 = 0
 result = []
 for i in x:
     max2 = max(0, max2 + i)
     max1 = max(max1, max2)

 print result
```

I want to add elements till the element which had the max sum. How do I add only whose elements to the result.

For ex. if `x = [4, -1, 5, 6, -13, 2]`
then result should be `[4, -1, 5, 6]`

Comment: So do you always want the subset to start at the beginning or your list, or could it start somewhere in the middle?

Comment: It's not quite clear what your algorithm is intended to be, but I'm pretty sure it's not going to work. You don't seem to handle the case where the best contiguous subset doesn't start at the start of the list.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062844/maximum-sum-sublist#15063394

Answer (score 9):

This is a classic problem in optimization, and it's called the [*maximum subarray problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem). Here's one possible dynamic programming solution in `O(n)`, using [Kadane's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm):

```
def max_val_contiguous_subsequence_idxs(seq):
    i = thisSum = maxSum = 0
    startIdx, endIdx = 0, -1
    for j in xrange(len(seq)):
        thisSum += seq[j]
        if thisSum > maxSum:
            maxSum = thisSum
            startIdx = i
            endIdx   = j
        elif thisSum < 0:
            thisSum = 0
            i = j + 1
    return (maxSum, startIdx, endIdx)
```

The above will return in a single pass a tuple with the maximum sum, the starting index and the end index of the subsequence. For example, using the sample input in the question:

```
lst = [4, -1, 5, 6, -13, 2]
maxSum, startIdx, endIdx = max_val_contiguous_subsequence_idxs(lst)

maxSum
=> 14
lst[startIdx:endIdx+1]
=> [4, -1, 5, 6]
```

Notice that the implementations shown in the wikipedia page (which look a lot like the solution you were aiming for) only give the maximum sum, but unlike my solution they don't tell you how to find the subsequence indexes in the array.