# Why my algorithm that try to find maximum subarray doesn't work?

Tags: python, algorithm

I try to implement this maximum subarray algorithm according to the book: Introduction to Algorithms(Chapter 4). It can run, but the result is not correct. I can't find the logical problem here. Thank you.

```
 def find_max_crossing_subarray(A,low,mid,high):      
    leftSum=float('-inf')
    result=0                   ## left_max_sum of midpoint
    maxLeft=0
    maxRight=0

    for i in range(mid,low,-1):
        result=result+A[i]        
        if result>leftSum:
            leftSum=result
            maxLeft=i

    rightSum=float('-inf')
    result2=0                     ##right_max
    for j in range(mid+1,high,1):
        result2=result2+A[j]
        if result2>rightSum:
            rightSum=result2
            maxRight=j
    Result=result+result2        
    return maxLeft,maxRight,Result


def find_maximum_subarray(A,low,high):
    if low==high:
        return low, high, A[low]
    else:
        mid=(low+high)//2
        leftLow,leftHigh,leftSum=find_maximum_subarray(A,low,mid)
        rightLow,rightHigh,rightSum=find_maximum_subarray(A,mid+1,high)
        crossLow, crossHigh,crossSum=find_max_crossing_subarray(A,low,mid,high)
        if leftSum>=rightSum and leftSum>=crossSum:
            return leftLow,leftHigh,leftSum
        elif rightSum>=leftSum and rightSum>=crossSum:
            return rightLow, rightHigh, rightSum
        else:
            return crossLow,crossHigh,crossSum

A=[1,2,30,21]
print (find_maximum_subarray(A,0,len(A)-1))
```

Comment: Lokks *a bit too long* for a python program to accomplish such a small task...

Comment: Have tried debugging and stepping through it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

In `find_max_crossing_subarray`, instead of `range(mid,low,-1)` use `range(mid,low-1,-1)` and instead of `range(mid+1,high,1)` use `range(mid+1,high+1,1)`.

Further explanation:

From the `range` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

> If step is positive, the last element is the largest start + i * step
>   less than stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest
>   start + i * step greater than stop.

Which means, for example, that `range(0, 5)` gives `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Also see Ryan's fix of the `Result` value.

Comment: Also consider using *reversed()* rather than a range with a negative step.  The former is easier to reason about and get correct.

Answer (score 0):

when low and mid is the same, the for loop won't work. Using while  to instead for is the better choice. The Result is also incorrect in the original version.

```
def find_max_crossing_subarray(A,low,mid,high):
    leftSum=float('-inf')
    result=0                   ## left_max_sum of midpoint
    maxLeft=0
    maxRight=0
    i=mid
    while i>=low:
        result+=A[i]
        if result>leftSum:
            leftSum=result
            maxLeft=i
        i-=1


    rightSum=float('-inf')
    result2=0 
    j=mid+1                    ##right_max
    while j<=high:
        result2+=A[j]
        if result2>rightSum:
            rightSum=result2
            maxRight=j
        j+=1
    Result=leftSum+rightSum       
    return maxLeft,maxRight,Result
```

Answer (score 0):

> Kadane's algorithm consists of a scan through the array values, **computing at each position the maximum (positive sum) subarray ending at that position**. This subarray is either empty (in which case its sum is zero) or consists of one more element than the maximum subarray ending at the previous position. The algorithm **only needs to keep track of the ending position** because the **implied starting position is just after the last position** at which the sum went negative; a higher sum can always be found by dropping any negative-sum prefix.

In essence, the simplest algorithm describes a solution in which you have to loop through the array and find the largest subarray that could exist before your current value.

To simplify that algorithm, you eliminate any negative numbers and keep your starting index where your previous sum is positive. You can do this because any array has a **minimum sum of zero for the empty array**.

Therefore, you can simplify your algorithm:

```
  def mssl(l):
    best = cur = 0
    for i in l:
        cur = max(cur + i, 0)
        best = max(best, cur)
    return best
```

*Credits* to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm) for the explanation.

*Similar question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062844/maximum-sum-sublist) with a great answer from user `nneonneo`*