# Is there any algorithm whose time-complexity is O(n^3) for Maximum Sum Sublist?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

When I read [the answer for the former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062844/maximum-sum-sublist/15063394#15063394)! on stack overflow, it said that it was possible to solve Maximum Sum Sublist for O(n).

And I also wrote the code whose computational complexity was O(n^2) .

However, I heard that there is algorithm to solve  Maximum Sum Sublist for O(n^3).

If you know it, I would appreciate if you could share it with me.

The code for O(n)

```
def mssl(l):
    best = cur = 0
    for i in l:
        cur = max(cur + i, 0)
        best = max(best, cur)
    return best
```

The code for O(n^2)

```
def solution(A):
    start = None
    end = None
    max_total = 0

    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(i, len(A)):
            tmp = sum(A[i:j+1])
            if max_total < tmp:
                max_total = tmp
                start = i
                end = j

    return max_total, start, end


if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = [18, -10, 30, 23, -26]
    ans = solution(A)
    print(ans)
```

I would like to know any algorithm to solve Maximum Sum Sublist for O(n^3).

Comment: One possibility is to repeat the first version `n^2` times.

Comment: The code you’ve identified as O(n^2) there is actually O(n^3). The `A[i:j+1]` step takes O(j − i) time.

Comment: making worse algorithms is trivial. just add extra throwaway work.

Comment: @Ry-♦ Could you explain to me why my code which I identified as O(n^2) is actually O(n^3) on the answer form rather than the comment?

Comment: @Paritosh Singh I know but I would like to know differences among O(n), O(n^2), and O(n^3) algorithms to solve Maximum Sum Sublist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A[i:j+1]
```

This part copies `j + 1 - i` elements.

```
for j in range(i, len(A)):
```

The sum of j + 1 − i for j from i to n − 1 (n = `len(A)`) inclusive is:

- the sum of j in the same range, which is

  - the sum of j for j from 1 to n − 1: (n − 1)n / 2 = n²/2 − n/2
  - minus the sum of j for j from 1 to i − 1: (i − 1)i / 2 = i²/2 − i/2
- plus the sum of 1 in the same range, which is 1(n − i) = n − i
- plus the sum of −i in the same range, which is −i(n − i) = −in + i²

Put it all together and you get n²/2 − n/2 + i²/2 − i/2 + n − i − in + i² = **n²/2 + n/2 + 3/2 i² − (n + 3/2) i** copies for the j loop.

```
for i in range(len(A)):
```

The sum of n²/2 + n/2 + 3/2 i² − (n + 3/2) i for i from 0 to l − 1 is:

- the sum of n²/2 + n/2: (n²/2 + n/2)n = n³/2 + n²/2
- plus 3/2 [the sum of i²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number): 3/2 (n − 1)(n − 1 + 1)(2(n − 1) + 1)/6 = (n − 1)(n)(2n + 1)/4 = n/4 (2n² − 2i + n − 1) = n³/2 − n²/4 − n/4
- minus (n + 3/2) times the sum of i: (n + 3/2)(n − 1)n/2 = (n² + 3/2 n − n − 3/2)n/2 = n³/2 + n²/4 − 3n/4

which comes to n³/2 + n²/2 + n³/2 − n²/4 − n/4 − n³/2 − n²/4 + 3n/4 = **n³/2 + n/2 copies**, for a typical time complexity measurement of O(n^3), not O(n^2).

(Sanity check: n³ + n/2 is always a whole number.)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
In this case, how's gonna be an algorithm whose time-complexity is O(n^2)?

Comment: @NPP: Similar to existing suggestions, you can add busywork like `for i in range(len(A) ** 2): pass` to the O(n) answer.