# Need help in Algorithms - Finding the outputted maximum sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pseudocode, greedy

I'm currently studying algorithms and I was curious about a homework problem (yeah.. I know) that I have been finding conflicting answers on.

In pseudocode the algorithm is:

```
Algorithm-1(A:array[1..n] of integer) sum,max:integer
sum = 0
max = 0
for i = 1 to n
    sum = 0
    for j = i to n
        sum = sum + A[j]
        if sum > max then
            max = sum
return max
```

Given the array, [-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,7,-8,9,-10] I found that the max value that the above function returns should be 4 based on my interpretation of the algorithm, but online the only two answers I've found are 14 and 10.

My understanding of this algorithm is that it takes the base array, finds its sum, and then takes the same array starting at the *next* index and finds that sum, and the value that's returned is the highest of these sums.

Basically if given the array of [1,2,-3,4,5] it looks at it this way:

Sum of [1,2,-3,4,5] = 9

Sum of [2,-3,4,5] = 8

Sum of [-3,4,5] = 6

Sum of [4,5] = 9

Sum of [5] = 5

And the final max value returned is 9 since 9 > 8 > 6 > 5

Based on this understanding, I'm thinking that the value of my array is 4 from the [6,7,-8,9,-10] sub array. Would that be correct?

Comment: The largest sum is the sum of all positive numbers.  You are not saying that the numbers have to be consecutive in the array.

Comment: @jdweng If we look at the second for loop it will iterate through the j = i element of the array to the end of that same array, so it seems to consider them consecutively. I don't see a situation where the algorithm would only add positive numbers to the sum.

Comment: The main problem here is that you're only considering subarrays that end with the last element. The one for 14 would be [6,7,-8,9]. In addition, there's a faster solution to the problem. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062844/maximum-sum-sublist seems to be the canonical question and answer for the algorithm

Comment: @CharlesGleason Based on how I see the algorithm above, maybe all sub arrays aren't considered since it seems each for loop will iterate to n every time, and since the arrays are set up as array[1..n] a sub array that doesn't include the values from i = j all the way to the last element shouldn't exist.

Comment: I do not know where you got the pseudo code.  Was it from the teacher or from the web?  I'm reading the requirements : "Find the largest sub of sub-arrays".  The pseudo code on the web could be a completely different problem.

Comment: @jdweng The pseudocode was from a teacher. As far as the title, that was a suggested edit that apparently isn't indicative of my case. The problem is: "Understand the following algorithm. Simulate it mentally on the following four inputs, and state the outputs produced (value returned) in each case: (a) A: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; (b) A: [─1, ─2, ─3, ─4, ─5, ─6, ─7, ─8, ─9, ─10], ; (c) A: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], (d) A: [─1, 2, ─3, 4, ─5, 6, 7, ─8, 9, ─10]. " with the pseudocode attached. I know the outputs for arrays A,B,C are 54, 0, 0 respectively but d is the issue.

Comment: @Carcanken I actually misread the indentation, so the "main problem" is not there. While the sums at the end of the for loop always represent subarrays that end with the last element, they're checked against the current max every time an element is added. So, for example, after the first line in every for loop, you're checking the one-element subarray at i. Nothing happens after the for loop, so the "final value" of sum isn't treated any differently than the intermediate ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, I suppose you are not understanding the concept of subarrays, Subarrays are basically any set of contiguous elements in an array. Let's take your example.

For

```
[-1,-2,-3,4,-5,6,7,-8,9,-10]
```

For every array of size N, there are N*(N+1)/2 Subarrays. The answer in this particular case is the subarray [6,7,-8,9] which returns the sum as 14.

Have a look at the below link for better understanding:
 [Kadane Algorithm for maximum sum subarray](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/amp/)

Comment: Thank you for your response, however the way I'm looking at the algorithm's loops is that the n variable as seen in "for i = 1 to n" and "for j = i to n" will always go to the end of the array since the array is denoted as array[1..n], therefore the [6,7,-8,9] summation won't occur, but [6,7,-8,9,-10] would. Perhaps this isn't wholly a subarray problem, but please point out where in the pseudo code the for loop wouldn't iterate through to the end of the array because that's the main thing that I'm led to believe.

Comment: @Carcanken The loop will definitely go till the end but the summation would definitely occur, consider when i=6, sum = 0, max = 4, now with every iteration you would add A[j] to sum making it 6 in the first iteration, thus max would now become 6, 13 in the second iteration making max as 13, 5 in the third iteration but max would still be 13 since it won't be updated and finally 14 in the 4th iteration making max 14.